# Swift and dynamic UITableView row height

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have some rows in the middle of my table that need to have their height resized based on content. the Detail label can have a very long list of CSV values, my attempt to figure it out is as follows:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if(indexPath.section == 0){
        return 176;
    }
    if(indexPath.section == 1){
        if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) {

            cell.detailTextLabel!.frame.size = CGSize(width: view.bounds.size.width - 115, height: 10000)
            cell.detailTextLabel!.sizeToFit()
            cell.detailTextLabel!.frame.origin.x = view.bounds.size.width - cell.detailTextLabel!.frame.size.width - 15
            return cell.detailTextLabel!.frame.size.height + 20
        }
    }
    return 44;
}
```

However I get an EXEC_BAD_ACCESS error on:

```
if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
```

Any ideas as to why I get this error or the right way to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to grab a cell that does not exist yet. The cells returned by `cellForRowAtIndexPath(_ indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell?` are the cells you create and return in `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell`. So you are trying to calculate the height for a cell that doesn't exist yet by fetching the cell (which again, does not exist yet). It seems like what you want is to prototype a fake placeholder cell that you can set up to get the height for your real cells. To do that, you can make a single cell as a property on your delegate/datasource class, set that cell up once, then return its height as you trying to do in your height method.

Comment: Hi Dima, thanks for the input! So, I might be misunderstanding something, but these cells are designed via the storyboard - shouldn't that have given them a prototype cell created in memory to begin with?